# Can anyone provide a hint for Webgoat 8's Deserialization exercise?

Tags: java, webgoat

Working on the Deserialization exercise in Webgoat (v. 8) 
[image: form presented in WebGoat]

The Burp extension "Java Deserialization Scanner" detects that this page is potentially vulnerable to the Hibernate 5 (sleep) payload.

However, the payload used in the scanner does not satisfy the exercise. ysoserial is the tool that can generate payloads but I was getting errors.

The following article helped 
[Java Deserialization — From Discovery to Reverse Shell on Limited Environments](https://medium.com/abn-amro-red-team/java-deserialization-from-discovery-to-reverse-shell-on-limited-environments-2e7b4e14fbef)
Here is What I tried:
compiled latest release of ysoserial with:

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests -Dhibernate5
```

generated the base64 encoded payload with:

```
java -Dhibernate5 -jar ysoserial-0.0.6-SNAPSHOT-all.jar Hibernate1 "Thread.sleep(5000)" | base64 -w0
```

(also tried "sleep(5000)", "sleep 5000")

This fixed the errors and resulted in a long base64 encoded string that I pasted into the form field (but now with the result that "the solution is not correct").

Has anyone solved this exercise?